# Unity Android Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, keystore

I have published my android game made with unity 4.6 on play store.
For the safety reason I had taken a backup of complete game on the pc(different drive).

Now I am trying export signed version of updated game but got this errors:

> Unable to read keystore and Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Note: Password is correct and key store is in the same game folder.

After spending some time on Google I got an idea that this error has occurred because I had created duplicate game folder.

Comment: What does "I had created duplicate game folder" means, exactly? You just duplicated the Unity project, with the keystores in it? Are you able to use this keystore to build the project?

Comment: Thanks for taking interest in my question... Yes, I had copied and pasted unity project folder in another drive on same PC to keep backup of project, with keystore in it. And when i try to use keystore to build signed apk I am getting the errors mentioned above. @Max Yankov

Comment: have you solved the issue?